# check which well known text can be transformed using geometry::STPolyFromText(

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, spatial-query

I have some data which I bulk import into this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    WellKnownText NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Some of the entries are not valid. So something like this:

```
SELECT geometry::STPolyFromText(WellKnownText,4326) FROM #Temp
```

does not work for all rows and thus falls over.

What is the best way to detect which WellKnownText are not valid? I have used MakeValid in the past - so ideally I would like to fix entries as much as possible.

PS:

This does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp 
WHERE geometry::STPolyFromText(WellKnownText,4326).STIsValid() = 0
```

PPS:

I chose a loop based approach in the end along those lines:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp1;

DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1;
DECLARE @MaxCounter INT;
DECLARE @Valid BIT;
DECLARE @ValidCounter INT;
DECLARE @WellKnownText NVARCHAR(MAX); 

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,  
    PostcodeFraction NVARCHAR(50),
    WellKnownText NVARCHAR(MAX),
    GeoJson NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
    Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,  
    PostcodeFraction NVARCHAR(50),
    WellKnownText NVARCHAR(MAX),
    GeoJson NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

BULK INSERT #Temp FROM 'D:\PolygonData.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');

ALTER TABLE #Temp ADD Id INT IDENTITY(1,1);

SELECT @MaxCounter = MAX(Id) FROM #Temp

SET @ValidCounter = 0;

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxCounter)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @WellKnownText = WellKnownText FROM #Temp WHERE Id = @LoopCounter;
        SET @Valid = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(@WellKnownText,4326).STIsValid();
        SET @ValidCounter = @ValidCounter + 1;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @Valid = 0;
    END CATCH

    IF(@Valid = 1)
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO #TEMP1
            SELECT Guid, PostcodeFraction, WellKnownText, GeoJson FROM #Temp WHERE Id = @LoopCounter; 
        END 

    SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1;       
END

PRINT @ValidCounter;

SELECT * FROM #TEMP1;
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data of valid and invalid data

Comment: That's the point I cannot identify which are valid and which aren't!

Comment: in your column [WellKnownText] are all your values in the following format? POLYGON ((5 5, 10 5, 10 10, 5 5))?

Comment: when you run 'SELECT * FROM #Temp 
WHERE geometry::STPolyFromText(WellKnownText,4326).STIsValid() = 0' do you get an error like Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 13 of the input. The input has ,.

Comment: If you're asking about catching unparsable WKT, does this help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66642/detecting-invalid-wkt-in-text-column-in-sql-server

Comment: @KamranFarzami yes

Comment: @LesH thanks for that - looks promising although it will involve a non set based approach. please propose as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments, some possible solutions

I guess you're really looking for a function that can be `CROSS APPLY`ed, something like

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp T
CROSS APPLY IsWKTValidFunc(T.WellKnownText, 4326) F
WHERE F.IsValid = <somecondition>
```

(Or even added to as computed column to give you a flag that's set on inserting your WKT)

### Stored Proc

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66642/detecting-invalid-wkt-in-text-column-in-sql-server has a simple SP that wraps `GEOMETREY::STGeomFromText` in a try catch block.

However, stored procs cannot be `CROSS APPLY`ed (or called from a UDF that can be) so this would result in a cursor based solution.

### UDF

A UDF can be cross applied, but can't have a `TRY-CATCH` block. You also can't call the above SP from a UDF. So not much use there.

### CLR UDF

Wrap the `GEOMETREY::STGeomFromText` call in a CLR UDF that can be `CROSS APPLIED`, can have try catch and other error checking, rules etc, and return a flag indicating valid text. I haven't tried this one out but this sounds like the best option if CLR is enabled in your environment.

Hope this gives you some ideas. Feedback in the comments to these suggestions appreciated.